# How to validate an API that generates a PDF?

Tags: validation, intellij-idea, karate

I need to validate an API that generates a PDF response by comparing it to a JSON response from a separate API. Does anyone have any advice on how to approach a setup like this in Karate framework?

I currently have a feature file for the PDF API, a separate one for the JSON API, and then a third feature file for the 'comparison'. My assumption is that I could convert both the PDF and the JSON responses to string and do a string to string compare using the match keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Karate has visual testing built-in so that may help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#compare-image

If you mean OCR, you may be able to reuse some code from Karate Robot: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-robot

If a binary comparison is sufficient the `match` keyword supports that already: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-text-or-binary